# How can I click javascript object with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

```
# -*- coding: utf-8-sig -*-
import os
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

MAIN_PAGE_URL = "https://ithub.korean.go.kr/user/total/database/corpusManager.do"
abspath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
driver = None

def load_browser():
    global driver

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36")

    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(abspath + r"\chromedriver.exe", options = options)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit()

def scrape_a_page():
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='tbl_list']//td[@class='lf']/a")))

    content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='tbl_list']//td[@class='lf']/a").get_attribute("href")
    driver.execute_script(content)

# RUN
load_browser()
driver.get(MAIN_PAGE_URL)
scrape_a_page()
```

I clicked a text(object in table) to move into a content of table,
but an error page displays.

Did host blocked automation working?
Or did I make an error?

Thank you for help.

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: I think chrome clicked the object "successfully", but an error page made by site host displays. (It is written in Korean - "You typed wrong url or page is deleted or changed. Check it again.") @Suban Dhyako

Comment: And, if I click the object in normal Chrome, it moves to content page successfully. But if I manually(not by python code) click it in Chrome webdriver window created with Selenium, it displays error page.

Comment: What does the _error page_ says?

Comment: It says "You typed wrong url, or page has been deleted or changed. Check it again." @DebanjanB

Comment: @berry2971, could you retry the website?  it looks broken from where I am.  I can only get that same error page.

Comment: @James Uhm, I see. I will inquire about it to institution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to execute the javascript independently, it is set to run on a mouse click.  You can use:

```py
def scrape_a_page():
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='tbl_list']//td[@class='lf']/a")))

    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='tbl_list']//td[@class='lf']/a")
    link.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I already tried code like yours, and I retried it now with your code. But also displays error page (created by host).

Comment: Even by navigating through a regular browser, I get the same page.  This indicates the website has broken links.  There is nothing you can do to fix that...

Comment: oh, really? I could successfully get right page... for 100% percentage... Then is it okay that I suppose host blocks specific browser or sth?